# How to determine from where was my application obtained?

Tags: android

I've been using this to determine the source of the installation of my app, However both lucky patcher and google play both return com.android.vending.

```
context.getPackageManager().getInstallerPackageName((context.getPackageName()))
```

I guess my question would be is there other methods for determining the installer that will help me further determine which of the two are being used to install my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Lucky Patcher deliberately fakes the installer to bypass any protection mechanisms based on that value, and unfortunately `getInstallerPackageName` is the only way to check who installed your application.